# Small unit tactics vs. larger group

Tags: pathfinder-1e, tactics

What is a good source for tactics for a small group (~5) of mid level (10th) characters vs. a much larger group (50-100) (mixed group of ~5th levels plus leader and a dozen trolls)

I'm interested in things like flying over the enemy and carpet bombing them using portable holes; using [seeming](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/spells/seeming.html) to appear as members of the group and outflanking/infiltrating.

I've had a look around and most of what I can find is for mass battlefield tactic systems, what I want is some good ideas for a smaller team to wreak havoc against a much larger (numerically) but lower level enemy.

The system is pathfinder, but these tactics could be generic for any given fantasy system.

Comment: This may very well be closed because it sounds a lot like a list question, or possibly off-topic as you're basically just looking for guerrilla tactics.

Comment: Guerrilla tactics, but when magical abilities are available.

Comment: What's the average level of the larger group? If they are lower level then a valid tactic would be "wade in and murder them because they can't hit your high armor class"

Comment: Pathfinder does not really provide rules for this outside of the mass combat from ultimate combat. I would look at those rules and make adjustments to the mass combat rules based off of the tactics the players use. If the strategy is effective, then apply a greater bonus to the attack for that sides mass combat phase.